# Filter not working with dynamic input and ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to filter records in my repeater on the basis of a input text box but it is working unexpectedly and not filtering the correct record.

**My html code:**

```
<input ng-model="txtTest" type="text" class="form-control" id="txtTest"></input>

<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="SampleData in SampleInfo|MaxAmountFilter:txtTest" ng-form="SampleForm">
        <td>
            <div>
                <input type="text" name="DateOfLoss" ng-Model="SampleData.DateOfLoss" </input>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>
                <input type="text" name="LossDesc" ng-model="SampleData.LossDesc"> </input>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**My Directive:**

```
    AngularApp.filter('MaxAmountFilter', function () {
        return function(AmountArray, AmountEntered ) {
          var filteredAmount = [];

          angular.forEach(AmountArray, function (amt) {
              if (AmountEntered >= amt.LossAmount) {
              filteredAmount.push(amt);
            }
          });

          return filteredAmount;

        };
    });
```

**My scope data -**

```
    $scope.SampleInfo = [
        { "DateOfLoss": "01/01/2014", "LossAmount": "100", "LossDesc": "sasa"}, 
        { "DateOfLoss": "01/01/2015", "LossAmount": "500", "LossDesc": "ssss" }, 
        { "DateOfLoss": "01/01/2011", "LossAmount": "102", "LossDesc": "ddd" }, 
        { "DateOfLoss": "01/01/2012", "LossAmount": "700", "LossDesc": "hhhh"}, 
        { "DateOfLoss": "01/01/2010", "LossAmount": "250", "LossDesc": "dsdsd"}


];
```

This is working fine for static values ie when I do not filter on the basis of input values of text box. What is wrong with the code. Please suggest!

**EDIT:** [Plnkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/taF8dKVlFxsosXzL3vdQ)
Type 101, 102 then it works but when you type 10000 in the text box It does not work. Now remove `MaxAmountFilter:txtTest` from the filter and simply add `MaxAmountFilter:10000` This will work.

Comment: "SamleInfo" is that a typo...?

Comment: Please provide a working plnkr or fiddle for it so that we can edit it.

Comment: @DemoUser, Yes that was a typo. It is fixed now. I will soon add plnkr link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input doesn't have an `ng-model="txtTest"`. So the text entered in the amount is not saved in `txtTest` and `txtTest` is thus undefined.

EDIT:

another problem is that you're using strings to represent numbers. See this [updated plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/R7grNWTwGdoePhLJ3BNj?p=preview). Using an input of type number, and replacing your strings in the objects by numbers make everything go fine.

Comment: I have added model, It was left mistakenly. It is still not working. Added plnkr.